# Rotate Transformation Matrix Around Point

Tags: python, numpy, 3d, homogenous-transformation

I have a 4x4 transoformation matrix `T0` as a starting pose.

Now I want to rotate `T0` with an 3x3 rotation matrix `R` around a `center` point to get a new pose `T1`.

```py
import numpy as np

T0 = np.eye(4)
R = np.array([[0.98480775, 0., 0.17364818],
              [0., 1., 0.],
              [-0.17364818, 0., 0.98480775]])
center = np.array([-2.00628613e-02, -1.26855529e+00, -3.45331795e+01])

# T1 = ?
```

How to calculate `T1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4397766). And the working code is below:

```py
import numpy as np

T0 = np.eye(4)
R = np.array([[0.98480775, 0., 0.17364818],
              [0., 1., 0.],
              [-0.17364818, 0., 0.98480775]])
center = np.array([-2.00628613e-02, -1.26855529e+00, -3.45331795e+01])

T = np.eye(4)
T[:3, :3] = R
T[:3, 3] = center - np.matmul(R, center)

T1 = np.matmul(T, T0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2093314/rotation-matrix-of-rotation-around-a-point-other-than-the-origin and remember that matrix multiplication in numpy uses matmul https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html.

I'm not sure why your original matrix is a 4x4 if you're in 3d space?

Comment: The original matrix is 4x4 because it has a position and a rotation